# Adding a class to a woocomerce div tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce with a WP theme I have developed. I need to add a class to the Woocommerce div on the product page toget the Woocommerce content to fit within my sites container.

I'm quite new to Wordpress/ Woocommerce.

Please could someone advise how I can do this.

I simply need to change

```
<div class="woocommerce"> to <div class="container woocommerce">
```

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to take a copy of the default WooCommerce template files and then create them for your own theme; there's a lot of documentation surrounding this.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#

`Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy the template into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.`

`Example: To override the admin order notification, copy: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php`

Comment: I am with your answer because touching the  core files is not a best practice whenever an update is made to the woocommerce it will destroy all your changes. best practice is make a copy of the file into your theme folder and use that file to make any changes to woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

there is two options to add class
1. search that particular div/class to woocommerce folder
2. add via jQuery

$('.woocommerce').addClass('container');

incase of multiple woocommerce class in your page please inherit that class from parent.

like:-

$('parentUniqueSelector .woocommerce').addClass('container');

for more detail please share hosted link or example code.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which template file I need to add the jquery into?

Comment: i am not sure about template file name, but if you are not able to find out template name, you can also add these script in any common page / file like header, i will suggest to write code within condition by checking length of that particular selector. 

condition like- if($('parentUniqueSelector .woocommerce').length){$('parentUniqueSelector .woocommerce').addClass('container');}

Answer (score 0):

In my case I work with Bootstrap 4 framework, in order to apply **.row** class to woocommerce div in "my account" page I simply use make-row() mixin, example :

```
.woocommerce-account{
  .woocommerce{
      @include make-row();
    }
  }
```

Also you can use make-container() mixin, it depends of your project needs.

More infos [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#example-usage)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add a container to every pages might be to use WooCommerce hooks.

To enable WooCommerce support for your theme, add the following lines to your functions.php file:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
   add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

After that, use the hooks `woocommerce_before_main_content` and `woocommerce_after_main_content` to add your HTML code before and after WooCommerce content:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', function() {
    echo '<div class="container">'; // Open the container before WooCommerce content
}, 10);

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', function() {
    echo '</div>'; // Close the div tag opened for the container
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_woocommerce_container_classes', 99, 1);
function add_woocommerce_container_classes( $the_content ) {

    $the_content = preg_replace('/class\=\"woocommerce\"/', 'class="woocommerce your-new-class"', $the_content);

    return $the_content;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).